# Generating image sizes when uploading through wp.media

Tags: metabox, uploads, media-library

Finding documentation on `wp.media` is really tough, so bear with me.

I'm creating a metabox to attach images to a custom post type. I'm able to get a media frame to open, have it accept uploads, and return the uploaded attachment ID.

However, images uploaded through my `wp.media` frame do not have image sizes generated for them. Is there a way to have them automatically generated? If not, what is a good approach for generating them manually?

My `wp.media` call looks something like:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".metabox-image").each(function(){
    var metabox = $(this);
    var input = $(".metabox-image-value", metabox);
    var frame;

    var openFrame = function() {
      if (!frame) {
        frame = wp.media({
          // Only show images that have been uploaded to this post
          library: {
            type: "image",
            uploadedTo : wp.media.view.settings.post.id
          }
        });

        frame.on("select", function(){
          var att = frame.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
          input.val(att.id);
        });
      }

      frame.open();
    };

    $(".metabox-image-select-button", metabox).on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      openFrame();
    });
  });
});
```

In my `save_post` action I simply save the attachment ID in a `post_meta` field. Later, when I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )` only a URL to the full-size image is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the "GD" php library is enabled. You can do so by adding `phpinfo();` to one of your php templates and then search the result for `GD` or `GD Support`.

[The GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) is used for image manipulation and resizing is one of those functions.

To enable GD on windows you can edit the php.ini file in your php installation and uncomment
the `php_gd2.dll` extension:

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll ; <-- THIS ONE
;extension=php_gettext.dll
```